# Setear valor que viene de una API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Traigo desde el back un array de objetos, donde uno de esos objetos tiene una propiedad llamada `temperament`. Esta propiedad guarda una valor de tipo String, ejemplo: "Feliz, Jugueton, Amigable". Mi idea es colocar este mismo String pero de la siguiente forma: "Feliz | Jugueton | Amigable". Desde un componente card he tratado de hacer lo siguiente:

```
  /*let temperament2;
    if(!createInDb){
         temperament2 = temperament.replaceAll(',','|');
    } */
    //console.log(temperament)
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <img src={image} width="80px" height="80px" alt=""/>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <h3>{temperament}</h3>
            <h3>{weight}</h3>
            <h3>{!!createInDb?"true":"false"}</h3>

        </div>
    )
```

He intentado hacerlo directamente desde el `<h3>`, también he intentado hacerlo desde el back:

```
let dog = dogs.data.map(el =>{
            temp = el.temperament.replaceAll(',','|')
            return{
                id:el.id,
                name:el.name,
                weight:el.weight.metric,
                height:el.height.metric,
                temperament:temp,
                image: el.image.url,
                life_span: el.life_span
            }
        })
```

y tampoco, he intentado hacer modificación a la propiedad *name* y con éxito, pero no la logro con la propiedad *temp*. No entiendo muy bien en dónde estoy fallando. Dejo la API a donde estoy haciendo la solicitud.
https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema en cuestión? ¿Da error? ¿Aparece el valor original? ¿Es `undefined`?

Comment: mientras no le implemente el replaceAll funciona bien, el problema es cuando se lo aplico, tanto en el back o en el front

Comment: Y el problema es...?

Comment: que no me deja setear la propiedad temperament, y quisiera colocarla de esta forma "hola | mundo"